# Using sudo inside non-priviledged docker container not working

Tags: docker, sudo, hostname

I don't want to be root inside a docker container.

But I have to modify some files which belong to root in a script.

I want to use sudo for this.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl wget python openssh-server sudo
RUN mkdir /grader
RUN mkdir /grader/week1
RUN mkdir /grader/week1/assignment2
ADD executeGrader.sh /grader/
RUN groupadd -g 1000 coursera
RUN useradd -g 1000 -u 1000 --shell /bin/bash coursera
RUN usermod -a -G sudo coursera
RUN mkdir /home/coursera
RUN chown coursera:coursera /home/coursera
RUN echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config
RUN echo "coursera ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
RUN chmod 777 /etc/hostname
USER coursera
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["/grader/executeGrader.sh"]
```

executeGrader.sh contains this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
id
sudo -u root -H bash -c "hostname localhost"
```

But I get this one :/

```
>>docker run -h sdfsdfsdf323 -u 1000:1000 -P stackoverflow 
uid=1000(coursera) gid=1000(coursera) groups=1000(coursera)
hostname: you must be root to change the host name
```

Any ideas?

Comment: By default you would be root inside docker container. Then why do you need to run the application as a regular user ?
 Why do you need to switch to root ? You can just use `sudo -H bash -c "hostname localhost"` in your script

Comment: I'm creating a grader for the coursera online learning platform and they only start it with a non-priviledged user. Your solution (sudo -H bash -c "hostname localhost") gives me the same error.

Comment: ...on my local docker installation using Ubuntu 16.04, not on coursera....btw.

Comment: Check [This answer --cap-add SYS_ADMIN](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8902#issuecomment-218911749). and also [vasi answer](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8902#issuecomment-241129543)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your support, this one was finally working for me:

```
export temphostname=`hostname`
sudo su -c "echo 127.0.0.1 $temphostname >> /etc/hosts"
```